# docker-compose keeps using old image content

Tags: caching, docker, docker-compose

We use our gitlab-ci to build fresh images with the latest version of our code.
These images are day to day built with the `latest` tag.
We tag images during the release process.

My problem is related to the `latest` tag.
We deploy automatically these images on servers to test our product.

However, on a test server if we pull the latest docker image (verified by its checksum), stop the compose and up it again, we sometime still have the content of the old image (for example a configuration file).

We tried with `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate` but it doesn't help.

The only way to fix it was:

`docker-compose down
docker system prune -f
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d`

Any better idea ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can ignore data from previous volume with this:

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --renew-anon-volumes`

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Answer (score 14):

I just had this problem in dev too. docker-compose up uses an old image even though I have built the latest image. And if I manually run docker run in latest image I can see the new changes.
What fixed for me is running:

`docker-compose up --build <your-service>`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup that was what I was looking for. `docker-compose up -d --build serviceX serviceY`. That will allow you to selectively update and start services and also their dependents.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, thanks!!

Comment: Assuming this was the default behavior in docker compose cost me an hour of time when trying to debug an error with docker not finding a shell script for ENTRYPOINT. Make sure to check this if you're getting errors no matter what changes you make!

Answer (score 9):

You can try

```
docker-compose down --rmi all
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Too bad this answer isn't more fleshed out, as it worked very well! Perhaps an opportunity for improvement/contribution/edit even for this comment-er. ☺️

Answer (score 7):

The process should be:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

If you have volumes, then those will be persistent by design. If you need your volumes to not be persistent, then you may want to reconsider having that data inside a volume, or you'll need to reset the volume on every redeploy with a `docker-compose down -v` to remove the containers **and** the volumes.

If you still have issues with this, make sure your install of docker and docker-compose are current.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch,

I know how docker is working.
As explained in my previous message the images have correctly been pulled.
The files not well updated **are not** in a mounted volume even if some volume are linked to this container somewhere else.

Comment: @David can you update your question with an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can try reproducing your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This works in my case:

docker-compose down --rm all  *// stops containers and deletes them after all*

docker-compose up -d --force-recreate  *// pulls new images and runs them*

Comment: Short article about our issue: https://vsupalov.com/docker-compose-runs-old-containers/