# docker-compose running old image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos

I have the most frustrating issue ever with docker-compose:

I push a new image to gitlab, run docker compose on the server and.. the old image runs.

- I have restarted docker
- I have cleaned everything (all images and all containers)
- I have done docker-compose pull follow by up
- I have tried docker-compose --force-recreate
- I have wiped /var/lib/docker/image

and.. I'm still getting a container with the old image.
I don't even know where it gets the image from since I have wiped them with docker rmi...

now, if I do a docker run gitlabimagepath, the new image runs properly.
so, on the same computer the issue is specifically happening with docker-compose, not with docker.

docker-compose pull is getting an image with the proper digest.
when I run it with docker-compose and get the old image, or I run with docker run, the inspection gives the same image sha256. So it looks like there is some old container that keeps being resurrected for docker-compose and never gets rebuilt

I can't think of a better question than 'what the hell?'

nothing from this similar question [docker-compose keeps using old image content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461035/docker-compose-keeps-using-old-image-content) helps at all.

The docker compose is very basic:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  leech:
    container_name: services_leech
    image: registry.gitlab.com/...:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - volume-leech:/app
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  volume-leech:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: leech-network
```

so, one permanent storage volume and this is it.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add your `docker-compose.yml` file?  Do you have volumes that are overriding the image content, for example?

Comment: @DavidMaze, just added the info

Comment: Using a named volume for `/app` causes this – the contents of the named volume take precedence over what's in the image, and since volumes are there to hold user data, its content does not get modified as the underlying image changes.  Is there a specific unit of data you're trying to preserve this way, or some other functional need for the volume?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, the app is capturing live data and storing it in files and then those files get eventually uploaded to a storage. So I thought I’d be able to preserve the files of the day that way, while being able to update the app. What I now understand is that the /app folder is used for both code.. and data so I guess I should use another name, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a named volume to be mounted on `/app`:

```yaml
volumes:
  - volume-leech:/app
```

Both the application code and its local data are stored in the volume.  Docker has no way to tell these apart, so even when the underlying image gets updated, the older code in the volume winds up taking precedence.

If you can reconfigure or restructure your application to store its data somewhere else, you can change the Docker setup to

```yaml
volumes:
  - volume-leech:/app/data
```

and then the main code in `/app` will come from the image, and only the data will be stored in the named volume.

Comment: The moment I saw your comment I realized that I had not even realized I was using the same folder for both code and temp files! And I kept looking in all the wrong places :)

Comment: I had a variation on this where mounted directories were overwriting good files in the image with (not supposed to be) old files from the mount. Your comment led to a fix and has made a whole dev team very happy, thank you!