# WORKDIR doesn't work when running docker-compose run on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It looks like the WORKDIR inside my Dockerfile doesn't work. I'm trying this on Windows 10. The same works perfectly on Mac.

Here are my project files:
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php_under_test:
    build: tests/DockerImages/${PHP_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs
  test_runner:
    build: tests/DockerImages/testRunner
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs
```

The `tests/DockerImages/testRunner` folder has only this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN echo 'memory_limit = 1024M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git zip unzip

WORKDIR /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs
```

If I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run test_runner /usr/local/bin/php tests/Tools/generate-stub-map` in cmd.exe in the same directory where docker-compose.yml lies, I would get:

```
C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs>docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run test_runner /usr/local/bin/php tests/Tools/generate-stub-map
WARNING: The PHP_VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating phpstorm-stubs_test_runner_run ... done
Could not open input file: tests/Tools/generate-stub-map
ERROR: 1
```

However, if I run the same using `-w`: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run -w /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs test_runner /usr/local/bin/php tests/Tools/generate-stub-map` - that would work. Output:

```
C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs>docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run -w /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs test_runner /usr/local/bin/php tests/Tools/generate-stub-map
WARNING: The PHP_VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating phpstorm-stubs_test_runner_run ... done
Parsing "/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs/tests/Tools/../../aerospike/aerospike.php"
Parsing "/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs/tests/Tools/../../aerospike/Bytes.php"
etc...
```

I can see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#options) that `-w` is outdated and I should use `--project-directory` instead, but doesn't work also:

```
C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs>docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --project-directory /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs run test_runner /usr/local/bin/php 
tests/Tools/generate-stub-map
WARNING: The PHP_VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: build path C:\opt\project\phpstorm-stubs\tests\DockerImages either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

I've tried to look for something related at `docker/compose` github issues but found none.

`docker version` output:

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.24
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:09:02 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.10.1 (82475)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm running Windows, so unix-like paths I've used `-w /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs` wouldn't work, would they?

Comment: Wait.... :-D `docker compose run -w [path inside container]` (not deprecated) and `docker compose -w [path on host]` (deprecated, use `--project-directory` instead) - they are different. I'd suggest to update `docker-compose` or switch entirely to `docker compose` and retry with a verified fresh built. I think there is something twisted. Before running, verify the folders exist inside the container using `docker exec -it test_runner /bin/shell`.

Comment: Not sure about your last comment regarding verifying. Do you mean `docker compose exec`? My services aren't constantly running, so I have to use `run` instead. In that case verifying works: https://i.gyazo.com/7e613da31ab28d68096092b50c918597.png I then tried running my original project using Compose V2 - without any luck. It looks like it still doesn't use WORKDIR inside the Dockerfile: https://i.gyazo.com/13ea8346a55efe5d2b28acafb43fc2db.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you built `test_runner` image once using `Dockerfile` of previous version without `WORKDIR` parameter and trying to re-run container using this outdated image.

You have to remove image manually or force rebuild it using `docker-compose build` (or `docker-compose up --build`) instead of `docker-compose run`

Also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461035/docker-compose-keeps-using-old-image-content) may be helpfull

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't try that before. Doing `docker compose build test_runner --no-cache` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`WORKDIR` from dockerfile corresponds to `working_dir` in compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#working_dir

Try to use

```
  test_runner:
    build: tests/DockerImages/testRunner
    working_dir: /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the different path of your whole project.

Location of your docker file  `C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs\`

Location of base of your project `/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs` so the exact whole path to your project base in reality is `C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs\opt\project\phpstorm-stubs` and so the files it is trying to find is actually at `C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs\opt\project\phpstorm-stubs\usr\local\bin\php tests\Tools\generate-stub-map`

So once you used the `-f docker-compose.yml` it by default thinks that your whole project is at `C:\Projects\phpstorm-stubs\` but when you use it with `-w /opt/project/phpstorm-stubs` it knows that base of your project path is here so it knows that `tests/Tools/generate-stub-map` is further ahead of it.

And lastly `--project-directory` requires the whole path from the base of current drive

To sum up my answer you need to use command

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --project-directory /Projects/phpstorm-stubs/opt/project/phpstorm-stubs run test_runner /usr/local/bin/php  tests/Tools/generate-stub-map`